# How to solve bug with GC and LOS in xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, garbage-collection

When i'm starting activity which should load some data i got this message and crash.

12-05 17:07:15.397 I/art     (19294): Starting a blocking GC Explicit

12-05 17:07:15.406 I/art     (19294): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 19MB/25MB, paused 190us total 9.002ms

12-05 17:07:15.527 I/art     (19294): Starting a blocking GC Explicit

12-05 17:07:15.537 I/art     (19294): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 25% free, 19MB/25MB, paused 195us total 9.283ms

12-05 17:07:15.657 I/art     (19294): Starting a blocking GC Explicit

12-05 17:07:15.667 I/art     (19294): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 25% free, 19MB/25MB, paused 188us total 9.330ms

Is there any way to solve this? And what exactly does it means?

Link to debug: http://pastebin.com/xQkax9NX

Comment: I don't think these messages are connected to the crash. Try to post the whole debugger output.

Comment: GC stands for Garbage collection. You seem to be loading way too much data in memory in this activity however I can't tell for sure unless you post the entire debugger output

Comment: I Added link to entire debugger output

Comment: I don't see any crash in this output. What exactly do you mean by "crash"? What is the error message you got?

Comment: When i click button, it should open activity which should load some data, it was working fine to time when i added one more data to load, and when i open this activity i got blackscreen and this messages in debugger output (GC_MAJOR, los etc.) i have crash only when open it with adb, else i have blackscreen.

Comment: Then try to post the output with adb, so we'll be able to see the crashing message and call stack

Comment: Now after few changes it does not crashes but i made a few tests and it looks like i'm using too much RAM, this GC allows only to use 31MB but it always blocking application when only 40% is free so i can use only 19MB. Is there anyway to free up memory on change how much it allows me to use?

Comment: GC is garbage collector. It frees memory deleting unused objects. It cannot allow or disallow anything... What makes you think it blocks your program? It seems that you draw some conclusions about your problems (which may be right or wrong) and then give us them as another problem to solve. I think that it would be better to present facts rather than conclusions - the problematic code, its result (like "error message" or "black screen"), debugger output etc. Otherwise it would be really hard for anyone in this community to help you...

Comment: I will send some code tomorrow

Comment: I also get the GC crashing my app, it goes into an infinite loop trying to clear memory, even though it is showing 28% free